# add a out of office appointment to selected day

Tags: vba, outlook

I know with VBA you can add appointments to the outlook calendar with a set date and time in the code but all I would like to do is add an appointment to my calendar between 7:00 and 9:30 on the selected day. Is it possible to use VBA for a selected day and make the status out of office as well?

I have found the following code but this adds the event to the selected times and not a specific time on the selected day:

```
Sub CreateAppointmentUsingSelectedTime() 
    Dim datStart As Date 
    Dim datEnd As Date 
    Dim oView As Outlook.view 
    Dim oCalView As Outlook.CalendarView 
    Dim oExpl As Outlook.Explorer 
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.folder 
    Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem 
    Const datNull As Date = #1/1/4501# 

    ' Obtain the calendar view using 
    ' Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.CurrentView. 
    ' If you use oExpl.CurrentFolder.CurrentView, 
    ' this code will not operate as expected. 
    Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer 
    Set oFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder 
    Set oView = oExpl.CurrentView 

    ' Check whether the active explorer is displaying a calendar view. 
    If oView.ViewType = olCalendarView Then 
        Set oCalView = oExpl.currentView 
        ' Create the appointment using the values in 
        ' the SelectedStartTime and SelectedEndTime properties as 
        ' appointment start and end times. 
        datStart = oCalView.SelectedStartTime 
        datEnd = oCalView.SelectedEndTime 
        Set oAppt = oFolder.items.Add("IPM.Appointment") 
        If datStart <> datNull And datEnd <> datNull Then 
            oAppt.Start = datStart 
            oAppt.End = datEnd 
        End If 
        oAppt.Display 
    End If 
End Sub
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There are three ways of creating a new appointment item in Outlook. Read more about them in the [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) article.

Looks like you just need to set the `Start` and `End` properties:

```
oAppt.Start = #7/7/2019 8:00:00 AM# 
oAppt.End = #7/7/2019 11:00:00 AM#
```

Comment: Can I change it to be dynamic to the selected day ?

Comment: You may check the `Explorer.Selection` property. But I don't think it will give you such information. Most probably you will have to use the `View` object (see the `CurrentView` property of the `Explorer` class).

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way. not sure if it's the best way but it works:

```
Sub addSchoolRunToCalendar()
    Dim datStart As Date
    Dim datEnd As Date
    Dim oView As Outlook.View
    Dim oCalView As Outlook.CalendarView
    Dim oExpl As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Const datNull As Date = #1/1/4501#

    Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set oFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set oView = oExpl.CurrentView

    ' Check whether the active explorer is displaying a calendar view.
    If oView.ViewType = olCalendarView Then
        Set oCalView = oExpl.CurrentView

        datStart = oCalView.SelectedStartTime
        datStart = Format(datStart, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " " & Format("07:00", "hh:mm")

        Set oAppt = oFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Appointment")
        If datStart <> datNull And datEnd <> datNull Then
            oAppt.Subject = "School Run"
            oAppt.Location = "Home"
            oAppt.BusyStatus = olOutOfOffice
            oAppt.Start = datStart
            oAppt.Duration = "150"
            oAppt.ReminderSet = False
        End If

        oAppt.Save

    End If

End Sub
```